# Convert Tensorflow 1.x code with custom loss into 2.x

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, compatibility

Suppose I have the following code written in Tensorflow 1.x where I define custom loss function. I wish to remove `.compat.v1.`, `Session`, `placeholder` etc. and convert it into Tensorflow 2.x.

How to do so?

```py
import DGM
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as spstats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm.notebook import trange

# Option parameters
phi = 10
n = 0.01
T = 4

# Solution parameters (domain on which to solve PDE)
t_low = 0.0 - 1e-10
x_low = 0.0 + 1e-10 
x_high = 1.0

# neural network parameters
num_layers = 3
nodes_per_layer = 50

# Training parameters
sampling_stages  = 2500  # number of times to resample new time-space domain points
steps_per_sample = 20    # number of SGD steps to take before re-sampling

# Sampling parameters
nsim_interior   = 100
nsim_boundary_1 = 50
nsim_boundary_2 = 50
nsim_initial    = 50
x_multiplier    = 1.1    # multiplier for oversampling i.e. draw x from [x_low, x_high * x_multiplier]


def sampler(nsim_interior, nsim_boundary_1, nsim_boundary_2, nsim_initial):
    ''' Sample time-space points from the function's domain; points are sampled
        uniformly on the interior of the domain, at the initial/terminal time points
        and along the spatial boundary at different time points. 
    
    Args:
        nsim_interior:      number of space points in the interior of U
        nsim_boundary_1:    number of space points in the boundary of U
        nsim_boundary_2:    number of space points in the boundary of U_x
        nsim_initial:       number of space points at the initial time
    ''' 
    
    # Sampler #1: domain interior
    t_interior = np.random.uniform(low=t_low, high=T, size=[nsim_interior, 1])
    x_interior = np.random.uniform(low=x_low, high=x_high*x_multiplier, size=[nsim_interior, 1])

    # Sampler #2: spatial boundary 1
    t_boundary_1 = np.random.uniform(low=t_low, high=T, size=[nsim_boundary_1, 1])
    x_boundary_1 = np.ones((nsim_boundary_1, 1))

    # Sampler #3: spatial boundary 2
    t_boundary_2 = np.random.uniform(low=t_low, high=T, size=[nsim_boundary_2, 1])
    x_boundary_2 = np.zeros((nsim_boundary_2, 1))
    
    # Sampler #4: initial condition
    t_initial = np.zeros((nsim_initial, 1))
    x_initial = np.random.uniform(low=x_low, high=x_high*x_multiplier, size=[nsim_initial, 1])
    
    return (
        t_interior, x_interior,
        t_boundary_1, x_boundary_1,
        t_boundary_2, x_boundary_2,
        t_initial, x_initial
    )


def loss(
    model,
    t_interior, x_interior,
    t_boundary_1, x_boundary_1,
    t_boundary_2, x_boundary_2,
    t_initial, x_initial
    ):
    ''' Compute total loss for training.
    
    Args:
        model:                          DGM model object
        t_interior, x_interior:         sampled time / space points in the interior of U
        t_boundary_1, x_boundary_1:     sampled time / space points in the boundary of U
        t_boundary_2, x_boundary_2:     sampled time / space points in the boundary of U_x
        t_initial, x_initial:           sampled time / space points at the initial time
    '''  

    # Loss term #1: PDE
    # compute function value and derivatives at current sampled points
    u = model(t_interior, x_interior)
    u_t = tf.gradients(ys=u, xs=t_interior)[0]
    u_x = tf.gradients(ys=u, xs=x_interior)[0]
    u_xx = tf.gradients(ys=u_x, xs=x_interior)[0]
    diff_u = u_t - u_xx + phi**2 * (tf.nn.relu(u) + 1e-10)**n
    # compute average L2-norm for the PDE
    L1 = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(diff_u))
    
    # Loss term #2: First b. c.
    u = model(t_boundary_1, x_boundary_1)
    bc1_error = u - 1

    # Loss term #3: Second b. c.
    u = model(t_boundary_2, x_boundary_2)
    u_x  = tf.gradients(ys=u, xs=x_boundary_2)[0]
    bc2_error = u_x - 0

    # Loss term #3: Initial condition
    u = model(t_initial, x_initial)
    init_error = u - 1

    # compute average L2-norm for the initial/boundary conditions
    L2 =  tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(bc1_error + bc2_error + init_error))

    return L1, L2


# initialize DGM model (last input: space dimension = 1)
model = DGM.DGMNet(nodes_per_layer, num_layers, 1)

# tensor placeholders (_tnsr suffix indicates tensors)
# inputs (time, space domain interior, space domain at initial time)
t_interior_tnsr     = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x_interior_tnsr     = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
t_boundary_1_tnsr   = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x_boundary_1_tnsr   = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
t_boundary_2_tnsr   = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x_boundary_2_tnsr   = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
t_initial_tnsr      = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x_initial_tnsr      = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

# loss 
L1_tnsr, L2_tnsr = loss(
    model,
    t_interior_tnsr, x_interior_tnsr,
    t_boundary_1_tnsr, x_boundary_1_tnsr,
    t_boundary_2_tnsr, x_boundary_2_tnsr,
    t_initial_tnsr, x_initial_tnsr
)

loss_tnsr = L1_tnsr + L2_tnsr

# set optimizer
starting_learning_rate = 3e-4
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
lr = tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(
    learning_rate=starting_learning_rate,
    global_step=global_step,
    decay_steps=1e5,
    decay_rate=0.96,
    staircase=True,
)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss_tnsr)

# initialize variables
init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

# open session
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.run(init_op)


try:
    model.load_weights("checkpoint/")
    print("Loading from checkpoint.")
except:
    print("Checkpoint not found.")

# for each sampling stage
for i in trange(sampling_stages):
    
    # sample uniformly from the required regions
    t_interior, x_interior, \
    t_boundary_1, x_boundary_1, \
    t_boundary_2, x_boundary_2, \
    t_initial, x_initial = sampler(
        nsim_interior, nsim_boundary_1, nsim_boundary_2, nsim_initial
    )
    
    # for a given sample, take the required number of SGD steps
    for _ in range(steps_per_sample):
        loss, L1, L2, _ = sess.run(
            [loss_tnsr, L1_tnsr, L2_tnsr, optimizer],
            feed_dict = {
                t_interior_tnsr: t_interior,
                x_interior_tnsr: x_interior,
                t_boundary_1_tnsr: t_boundary_1,
                x_boundary_1_tnsr: x_boundary_1,
                t_boundary_2_tnsr: t_boundary_2,
                x_boundary_2_tnsr: x_boundary_2,
                t_initial_tnsr: t_initial,
                x_initial_tnsr: x_initial,
            }
        )
    
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(f"Loss: {loss:.5f},\t L1: {L1:.5f},\t L2: {L2:.5f},\t iteration: {i}")

    model.save_weights("checkpoint/")
```

I tried searching how to implement custom loss functions with model as an argument, but couldn't implement it.

Comment: I tried to do model.compile(...), but I don't know how to pass a loss function since it takes the model as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For model.compile there is a loss argument for which you can pass the Loss function. May be a string (name of loss function), or a tf.keras.losses.Loss instance. For example

```
Model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())
```

If you have created your custom loss function you can also pass that loss function to the loss argument by providing the name of that loss function. For example

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss_fn)
```

Thank You.